# external_defu_default(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

error: `nuxt - external_defu_default(...) is not a function`

I tried to generate nuxt app but i got this errors, can somebody tell me how to solve this?

I'm using nuxt bridge and tailwind, i thought it might have something wrong with the packages, i've tried to uninstall unused packages but i still got the errors.

node version: v16.14.0
nuxt version: nuxt bridge-edge

Here are the logs:

````
  at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)  
  at new runtime_BaseScheme (./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:14075:28)  
  at new LocalScheme (./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:14121:5)  
  at auth (./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:14314:35)  
  at createApp (./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:14632:11)  
  at async module.exports.__webpack_exports__.default (./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/prerender/chunks/app/server.mjs:14781:7)  
  at async renderToString (./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:278:19)  
  at async ./node_modules/.cache/nuxt/prerender/chunks/renderer.mjs:611:20  
  at async ./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:420:19  
  at async nodeHandler (./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:370:7)  
  at async ufetch (./node_modules/unenv/runtime/fetch/index.mjs:9:17)  
  at async generateRoute (./node_modules/nitropack/dist/chunks/prerender.mjs:2172:17)  
  at async Task.task (./node_modules/nitropack/dist/chunks/prerender.mjs:2194:29)```
````

Comment: You haven't provided enough info about the error, which means nobody can help you fix it. Consider explaining how you get to this error. What node version are you using? What package manager are you using?

Comment: Hi, I have the exactly same problem. Do you find a solution @Dzaky Fawwaz ?